# jquery mobile applies unnecessary extra height on first visit to pages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've searched around but couldn't find anything useful (maybe I don't know what to look for?).
in a multi-page index.html, if I do `data-transition='none'`, destination page will have some extra height that will force the vertical scrollbar (and of course the page will scroll) while page content height does not exceed viewport height.
I should note, this happens only in pages with `data-transition` attribute set to none. **change it to slide or something and the height problem is gone**. also it happens only on first visit. go to page, navigate to some other page, head back and the page height is fixed.
it looks like a jquery height calculation problem. or at least I AM making jquery calculate the height wrong.
problem exists in FF and chrome but not IE 9.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>I'm Fixed</h1>
</div><!-- header -->

<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h1>HOME</h1>
    </div>
</div><!--p1-->

<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
         <h1>OTHER PAGE</h1>
    </div>
</div><!--p2-->

<div data-role="page" id="p3">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h1>THE END</h1>
  </div>
</div><!--p3-->

<div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a href="#p1" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">HOME</a>
    <a href="#p2" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">OTHER PAGE</a>
    <a href="#p3" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">THE END</a>
</div><!-- footer -->
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(ev, ui){
    $("#header").toolbar({theme:"a", position:"fixed"});
    $("#footer").toolbar({theme:"a", position:"fixed"});
});
```

here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jikacu/3/edit?html,js,output

1. click on "OTHER PAGE", the page will load and have extra height.
2. click "HOME".
3. click on "OTHER PAGE" and you'll see that page height is fixed.

**JQUERY 2.1.1 - JQM 1.4.5** - multi-page html with external persistent toolbars.

why is this happening?

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question, not just posting it on any external link

Comment: Initialize external widgets on `.ready()` not on `pagecreate` or `pageinit`. This is one of the rare cases where ready is used.

Comment: huh! I'm gonna go and do that. thank you. quick question: is this mentioned in jqm docs? not checking it at this moment, but never saw it. also samples in docs don't use `.ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this fix:**

Remove:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(ev, ui){
    $("#header").toolbar({theme:"a", position:"fixed"});
    $("#footer").toolbar({theme:"a", position:"fixed"});
});
```

...and add:

```
$( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
```

Comment: thank you. problem is gone. can you explain why is this happening?

Comment: The min-height for the other two pages, when first visiting, is calculated wrong. When looked at the second time, the min-height gets re-calculated correctly. I'm actually not sure why that happens. Perhaps someone can better explain the source of the problem?

Comment: yes, I've recorded min-height sets on each page on pageshow. actually jquery sometimes does it wrong on second visit too, meaning min-height even changes again on 3rd visit. but why? and again, thank you for your time

Comment: I have looked into it some more... It seems like on page change, the calculation is done before the header and footer is accounted for, causing the min-height to be more than it should. I tried putting the header and footer inside of each page div and that fixed the problem as well. Looking at other mobile page examples and the jQuery Mobile docs, the page header and footer should always be inside the data-roll="page" div

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the cleaner fix.

Comment: Call reset function when you inject toolbar into active page. The OP is using external toolbar http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-external/

Comment: Thanks Omar!! that is awesome. I have updated my answer to include the fix you have pointed to.